# How Context object is working in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapper

I'm learning hadoop. And for word count I have some code for mapper. Its same with one question which already exists on stack over flow but that's answer could not satisfy our doubts.

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;import import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;importorg.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        for (String word : line.split(" ")) {

            if (word.length() > 0) {
                context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here we can see map method of Mapper class gets overriding and Context context came into existence. When I have opened the hadoop jar files found that Context is an abstract class in Mapper class in hadoop library which is implementing MapContext interface like below

```
public abstract class Context implements MapContext<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {
        public Context() {
        }
    }
```

My doubts:

1. In my WordCountMapper code, Context object is storing the output key value pairs. How data gets stored into Context object? Is it a kind of list? Where I can its implementation in library?
2. Who is creating the Context class object? Since its a abstract class, which one is a concrete class for the same?
3. Is it hadoop framework itself who creates a Context object one we copy the data into HDFS? How it borns?

Any suggestion ?

Comment: @cricket_007, But in those answers not having facts that how its stores in it ? And secondly who triggers them to be born ....? Are those APIs ?

Comment: It writes Writables. It stores metadata about a Job. It stores the Hadoop configuration object. You can define and store your own counters in it within a map... Read the JavaDoc... It's all an API

Comment: @cricket_007, Writables are all about byte streams. So you mean context object writing outputs directly  into byte streams ?

Comment: No, not directly. Look at the code... `context.write(new Text(word)`

Comment: But there is a `BytesWritable` class

Comment: @cricket_007, Look at this context.write(new Text(word),new IntWritable(1));, Its a Mapper output which is context object is writing somewhere. Could you please tell me where I can find this write method so that I could see where its writing actually ?

Comment: I'm  not actually sure where it writes. Nor, should you care until you think it is a problem. It buffers in memory somewhere until the task finishes, then is shuffled and sorted prior to a Reduce task

Comment: @cricket_007, fair enough...!!